# Why does updating properties in one object change another object?

Tags: javascript, object, copy

I'm loading JSON data into an object via ajax, copying that object to new objects (initData and newData). When I change the property of newData, the property of initData also changes. Why is this happening?

```
var initData = {};
var newData = {};    

function load_data(NDB_No){
    $.getJSON(('scripts/jsonencode.php?q=' + NDB_No), function(data) {

        for (prop in data){
            initData[prop] = data[prop];
            newData[prop] = data[prop];
        }

    console.log('init data: ' + initData.properties.Protein); // "init data: 0.259"
    console.log('new data: ' + newData.properties.Protein); // "new data: 0.259"

     var n = parseFloat(newData.properties.Protein);
     newData.properties.Protein = n+1;

    console.log('init data: ' + initData.properties.Protein + 'new data: ' + newData.properties.Protein); 
    // "init data: 1.259 new data: 1.259"
    // why are these the same when I only updated newData object?


    });


}
```

Comment: To note, "why are these the same when I only updated newData object?"...they are the same before you updated the newData object. They both point to the same location in memory. Kolink expands on this in his answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like `data[prop]` is an object (since you are later referring to `newData.properties.Protein`). Objects are always passed by reference, with the variable just being a pointer to it.

Since you're getting JSON in the first place, your object is JSON-able, so you can use that to "clone" the object:

```
$.getJSON(...,function(data) {
    initData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
    newData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

This will ensure that the objects are separate. There are other ways to do this, but this one avoids the manual recursion by using built-in methods (always faster)

Comment: Thanks this worked, will choose this answer when avail. What is the proper vocabulary used for copying objects? Trying to read up on it.

Answer (score 0):

This sets both to reference the same memory space:

```
initData[prop] = data[prop];
newData[prop] = data[prop];
```

...so when you change `newData`, you also change `initData`. Instead of assigning by reference, you'll want to create a copy.  I have to run, so I can't provide an example of that right now.